# How is the (rare) Locative Plural formed?

Tags: plural, locative, word-formation

If I understood right the Locative is only to be formed in singular (e.g. domi, ruri, ...).

But when it comes to words (especially cities / small islands) that **only exist in Plural** (e.g. Athenae) we have to **form a Locative plural**, right?

How is that Locative plural formed?
Is it just always **similiar to the Ablative Plural** (eg. Athenis)?

Comment: Note: *domus* is not in the second declension and the genetive is not *domi*.

Comment: My Stowasser (I think you know Stowasser) and multiple websites tell me that both u and o declension exist for domus. Isn't that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allen & Greenough name locative plural endings for the [1<sup>st</sup>](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/1st-declension-case-forms), [2<sup>nd</sup>](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/2nd-declension-case-forms) and [3<sup>rd</sup>](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-locative-case) declensions. They are all identical to the dative/ablative:

- **Athenis** *at Athens* (1<sup>st</sup> declension)
- **Philippis** *at [Philippi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippi)* (2<sup>nd</sup> declension)
- **Trallibus** *at [Tralles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayd%C4%B1n)* (3<sup>rd</sup> declension)

For the 4<sup>th</sup> and 5<sup>th</sup> declensions, no locative plurals appear to be attested (and not many singulars either).

Answer (score 0):

The original locative plural had the *-su or *-oysu ending (i.e., Athenasu), then modified and merged with the ablative.

References:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locative_case
2. https://www.corsi.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid114728.pdf